# React howler - unable to load core function

Tags: reactjs, howler.js

I'm using [React-Howler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-howler) to play a sound in my React app. At the top of my component I have the following imports:

```
import ReactHowler from 'react-howler';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class SamplesInnerLrg extends Component { 

playSampleAction(sampleSource) {

    var sound = new Howl({
      src: [sampleSource]
    })

}
render() {
    <div>
        <div onClick={this.playSampleAction("url to some source")}>Play</div>
        <ReactHowler src={"url to some source"} playing={true} />
    </div>

}
```

When I render the component out I it plays me the sound from the the  component but when I click the div saying "play" it tells me Howl is not defined. I've tried defining Howl in 2 ways:

```
var Howl = require('howler').Howl;
```

or

```
import { Howl } from 'react-howler'
```

but neither work. Not sure what i'm doing wrong to import Howl!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you are including the Howler script in your browser:

```
<script src="/path/to/howler.js"></script>
<script>
    var sound = new Howl({
      src: ['sound.webm', 'sound.mp3']
    });
</script>
```